# dotnet build task failed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, yaml

New to the forum as rookie, might ask something simple, please help me.

Running a yml pipeline by using a self hosted ado agent (Server 2019 data centre image). the dotnet build kees failing with the below error:

> Build FAILED.
>
> C:\agent_work_tool\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1221,5):
> error MSB3971: The reference assemblies for
> ".NETFramework,Version=v6.0" were not found. You might be using an
> older .NET SDK to target .NET 5.0 or higher. Update Visual Studio
> and/or your .NET SDK.
> [C:\agent_work\3\s\xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Tests.Api\xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Tests.Api\xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.Tests.Api.csproj]
>
> 0 Warning(s)
>
> 1 Error(s)
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.40

I have checked the self hosted agent and make sure that dotnet 5 and 6 are both installed. still not working. tried almost everything but no luck.VS2022 is also installed (2017 and 2019 are installed parallel as well)

The reason we are using the self hosted agent is that the test task after build is needing to access some private endpint.

Comment: There has to be some setting on that agent on which version of SDK is uses when doing the build ! Maybe you need to check that ? Sometimes there is setting with path to SDK inside settings

Comment: Add `dotnet --info` to the start of the build to verify the .NET SDK is correctly installed. And make sure you have the SDK, not only the runtime.

Comment: thank you @J.Memisevic. I am waiting for my permission on the agent pool then I will update the agent then report back. as current show in the capability of the agent that the dotnet path is still pointing to sdk 3 for some reason even 5 and 6 are both installed.  thanks again

Comment: thank you @PMF I have added the script before the build and it is listed as SDK 6.0.300. thanks again

Answer (score 4):

I got this exact error building a Container. The problem was this old image in the dockerflie:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1-alpine AS build
```

This fixed it:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
```

Comment: All this means is that you pulled a MS container that was setup correctly with the relevant dlls in the right place to begin with. It doesn't say anything about what that location is or how to set it up outside of docker.

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. The MSBuild environment vairables was pointing to dotnet 3.1.249 and for some reason when dotnet 6 installed the variables were not updated even inside same folder. Manually updated the variable and restarted the agent service. It appreas in the agent capability list as 6. Build works now. Thank you eveyone. I guess rookie made a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I don't have enough reps to comment on [xuy22's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72727180/8411099), so just adding to that, the environment variable name is *MSBuildSDKsPath*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34005982)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've had the same problem after converting the solution from netcore3.1 to .net6 by using the "Upgrade Assistant" tool from MS.
At the end it appeared that the tool didn't converted one of the projects, and it was still left as netcore3.1. Even trying to convert that single project explicitly it didn't worked either. I just had to do that by hand and it solved the build issue.

Comment: AFAIK the Upgrade Assistant is only for convert NET Framework projects to net6, which is why your netcore3.1 project was untouched.

Answer (score 0):

use cmd and run this query, it returns installed .NET SDKs and .NET Runtimes

```
dotnet --info
```

[image]

check if SDK which you need is in the list, if not install it, before that, pay attention to what version (x86/x64) of Visual Studio you have installed and what version (x86/x64) of the SDK you are installing, If it does not match, there will be an error again